# Is there a limit to the depth of nested routes you can do in Nuxt.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I would like to know if there is a limit to the depth of [nested routes](https://nuxtjs.org/guide/routing) you can do in Nuxt.js? Please confirm your response with a trusted reference.

Comment: This feels like a very abstract question. How many do you need? What did you try already?

Comment: It not an abstract question as the information I am looking for is very specific and not broad. I am asking because I stumbled on some issue that makes me think there is a limit for the number of nested routes I can do. What is this issue and my error message? Well, I just want to be informed, if possible, about what I asked for :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nuxt passes [all files](https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/blob/dev/lib/builder/builder.js#L296) found with the glob `pages/**/*.{vue,js}` (`**` means as many subdirectories as the OS can handle) to the createRoutes() method.

I also couldn't find a limitation in the [createRoutes()](https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/blob/dev/lib/common/utils.js#L257) method.

However, with deep nesting you're adding (unnecessary?) complexity to your system and at some point you might run into the limits of how long an url can be.
I recommend to keep the nesting shallow.